How to remove Command Palette from MS Access
In MS Access, when I open a query in SQL View, all the text in the tab is now displayed in a font about 5 times normal with each line numbered. A right click in the tab window produces a pop-up showing:
•   Change All Occurrences Ctrl-F2
•   Cut
•   Copy
•   Paste
•   Command Palette F1
when normally it shows just Cut, Copy, Paste.
When I start a new query (Create, Query Design, right click, select SQL View), I first have to save the query. Normally it just opens up the query tab. And when I open an existing query, it takes maybe 2 seconds for the tab to be populated with the statement.
This started 2 days ago. When I closed the .accdb file, it was fine. The problem began the next day. I changed nothing, updated no software, and did not shut down the computer.
Eventually I started opening other .accdb files; they all have the same problem. But when I opened up some from a year ago, the problems were not there, no numbered lines, no Command Palette, no odd create queries.
By now you see that I think Command Palette is the issue. I've learned what it offers and it looks pretty useful. I just don't want it.
I hope this is enough detail. And, as always, thank you (whoever knows how to fix it).
I'm running Windows 10 Pro, using Microsoft 365, everything is fully up to date

I found the answer (I don't remember where) and it's really simple:
Open Options - File > Options
Select Current Database
Deselect Enable Monaco SQL Editor
For the curious, it's located in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ACCMonaco\monaco.html
It was added around July, 2024 to "power VS Code". I don't remember being told about this. It does have a lot of good features but I'm just too old to retrain myself.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
